# Functions don't call on scrapy/webcrawler

Tags: function, web-scraping, callback, scrapy

Can anyone tell me why ParseLinks and ParseContent are not called? The rest runs and prints/appends/does stuff but i get tumbleweed from the teo parse functions. Any further errors information/advice also welcome.

```py
import scrapy
import scrapy.shell
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


Websites = ("https://www.flylevel.com/", "https://www.latam.com/en_us/")
links = []
D = {}
#D = {main website: links: content}
def dictlayout():
    for W in Websites:
        D[W] = []

dictlayout()

class spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "spider"
    start_urls = Websites
    print("request level 1")
    def start_requests(self):
        print("request level 2")
        for U in self.start_urls:
            print("request level 3")
            yield scrapy.Request(U, callback = self.ParseLinks)
            print("links: ")
            print(links)


    def ParseLinks(self, response):
        Link = response.xpath("/html//@href")
        Links = link.extract()
        print("parser print")
        print(link)
        for L in Links:
            link.append(L)
            D[W]=L
            yield response.follow(url=L, callback=self.ParseContent)

    def ParseContent(self, response):
        content = ParseLinks.extract_first().strip()
        D[W][L] = content
        print("content")
        print(content)

print(D)
print(links)


process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(spider)
process.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `ParseLinks` is actually called. The thing is that you are trying to extract a href from a html tag. This line `Link = response.xpath("/html//@href")` probably breaks your code. Try `Link = response.xpath("//a/@href")` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I changed this, and also corrected some errors: I now have the same formatting with `def ParseLinks(self, response):
        Link = response.xpath("/html//@href")
        Links = link.extract()
        print("parser print")
        print(link)
        for L in Links:
            link.append(L)
            D[W]=L
            yield response.follow(url=L, callback=self.ParseContent)`  but now i have an indentation error for the links parse part.